# ORMLite how to make this query?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I want to make this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one INNER JOIN table_two ON
    table_one.column_foreign_id = table_two.id WHERE table_two.column_one
    <= table_two.column_two AND table_one.column_one = [param];
```

I tried:

```
QueryBuilder<TableTwo, Integer> tableTwoQb = getTableTwoDao().queryBuilder();
tableTwoQb.selectColumns(TableTwo.COLUMN_ONE, TableTwo.COLUMN_TWO); 
QueryBuilder<TableOne, Integer> tableOneQb = getTableOne().queryBuilder();
SelectArg columnOneSelectArg = new SelectArg();
tableOneQb.where().eq(TableOne.COLUMN_ONE, columnOneSelectArg);
tableOneQb.join(tableTwoQb);
```

But I can't make the `WHERE` between two columns in `table_two`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think its what you are trying to accomplish

```
tableOneQb.where().le(columnOneSelectArg, columnTwoSelectArg).and().eq(columnOneSelectArg, "something");
```

le is <=

Try taking a look [here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html) if that doesn't help.

Comment: I need a Join and compare with <= two columns in same table. With queryRaw Can I use parameters?